# How to delimit this cypher query because there is a syntax error caused by the label name

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This Cypher statement causes a syntax error:

```
CREATE (mediawiki-1.27:Schema { key: mediawiki-1.27, name:mediawiki-1.27})
```

The error seems to be caused by the - character in the node label:

```
Invalid input '1': expected whitespace, [ or '-' (line 1, column 19 (offset: 18))

"CREATE (mediawiki-1.27:Schema { key: mediawiki-1.27, name:mediawiki-1.27})"
```

Answer (score 2):

Dashes and dots are not allowed in variable names. You can surround the variable name with backticks to escape it.

Also I'm guessing your key and name values are strings, in which case make sure to surround them with quotes:

```
CREATE (`mediawiki-1.27`:Schema { key:'mediawiki-1.27', name:'mediawiki-1.27'})
```